# Scrollbar for no content

Tags: html, css, scroll, include, overflow

I have a header that I want to include (with php) to all my pages. When I do it, an x-scrollbar apears scrolling outside my page and showing a blank bit of page.[image]

The page should end in the blue div.
I've tried settig "overflow-x:hidden", but that also hiddens the y scrollbar.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS here. We can't help you if we don't even have the code to examine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its much easier to get help if you provide some Code!!
However,  the html inside your outer html which is showing the bar, has dimensions that are bigger than their parent(outer) html.
Setting the width of the inside html to 100% will depend on their CSS position attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the width on the header bar to `width:100%`, this way the blue will stay inside the page and the scroll bar may not appear